# Group Select in an Only row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    loadNumber, 
    CASE 
        WHEN E.Clave = 'LOD' THEN FechaEvento 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Load Date USA', 
    CASE 
        WHEN E.Clave = 'DAA' THEN FechaEvento 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Colocacion AA',
    CASE 
        WHEN E.CLAVE = 'RPD' THEN FechaEvento 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Docs Listos',
    CASE 
        WHEN E.Clave = 'IDT' THEN FechaEvento 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Llegada MX',
    CASE 
        WHEN E.Clave = 'ULD' THEN FechaEvento 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Descarga MX'
FROM
    OrdenEvento OE
INNER JOIN 
    Evento E ON OE.idEvento = E.ID
WHERE 
    loadNumber = '60317'
GROUP BY 
    loadNumber, e.Clave, FechaEvento
```

I have this SQL, trying to gather all in one single row. My goal if there is a number that match with the cases enter and if there is not a single row with full NULL Values, or only a few matches  and others with Null Values

| loadNumber | Load Date | Colocacion AA | Docs Listos | Llegada MX | Descarga MX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | 2023-12-18 14:21:44.820 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2023-12-18 14:28:52.877 | NULL |
| 60317 | 2023-12-18 14:24:39.730 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | 2023-12-18 14:28:02.197 | NULL | NULL |
| 60317 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2023-12-18 14:29:04.193 |

This is the current result
and this is the wanted result

| loadNumber | Load Date | Colocacion AA | Docs Listos | Llegada MX | Descarga MX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60317 | 2023-12-18 14:24:39.730 | 2023-12-18 14:21:44.820 | 2023-12-18 14:28:02.197 | 2023-12-18 14:28:52.877 | 2023-12-18 14:29:04.193 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some aggregation to collapse all those rows to one row per loadNumber.

That also means your GROUP BY should only be loadNumber.

```
SELECT
  loadNumber, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN E.Clave='LOD' THEN FechaEvento ELSE NULL END)   AS 'Load Date USA', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN E.Clave='DAA' THEN FechaEvento ELSE NULL END)   AS 'Colocacion AA',
  MAX(CASE WHEN E.CLAVE='RPD' THEN FechaEvento ELSE NULL END)   AS 'Docs Listos',
  MAX(CASE WHEN E.Clave='IDT' THEN FechaEvento ELSE NULL END)   AS 'Llegada MX',
  MAX(CASE WHEN E.Clave='ULD' THEN FechaEvento ELSE NULL END)   AS 'Descarga MX'
FROM
  OrdenEvento OE
INNER JOIN
  Evento E
    ON OE.idEvento=E.ID
WHERE
  loadNumber='60317'
GROUP BY
  loadNumber
```

Comment: Yes!!!, Thanks a lot! This is exactly what i was looking for, I'll keep saved for further queries. Have a nice day!

Comment: There has got to be a duplicate of this question... rather than re-answering.

Comment: @DaleK if you find a good canonical example, let me know. I've seen this question numerous times in slight variations, but haven't found "The one"